# Grub does not list windows after crunchbang installation

Tags: grub, dual-boot, boot-menu, crunchbang

I have a couple of years of experience with ubuntu, but this is my first time with a non-ubuntu based distribution. I managed to successfully install Crunchbang from a bootable usb stick, created with unetbootin (my hom laptop's cd drive is dead) and at the end of installation, it asked me whether I wanted to install grub. It said that it detected the windows operating system that was already there and that it should be fine if all my operating systems are listed.

So, I let it install grub and now when I boot into my machine only a couple of Crunchbang listings appear in the grub boot menu. My windows has become inaccessible.

With the little experience I had, I tried to look for the menu.lst file which I expect to list the entries that would be shown in the grub boot menu. But I couldn't find that file. Perhaps crunchbang puts it in a different location?

I want to get my windows be listed in the grub boot menu. Any ideas?

**Edit:** From a comment on the question [Editing grub menu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/editing-grub-menu) I came to know the location of the boot menus, as `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and that file exists on my crunchbang system. I now need to know how and what to add to it to get my windows.

**Edit 2:** From the same question as above, I learned to do `sudo update-grub` which did put my windows entry in my grub boot listing and everything is fine. But I would still like to know... why wasn't it there initially when crunchbang did detect it and said that it would be added. Thanks.

Comment: if crunchbang detected it... I'd say it has a bug in its installer if it didn't add it.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely looks that way. I also doubt if it only occurs when installed through usb disk, not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, the solution is to run `sudo update-grub` from Crunchbang and the next time you boot, windows should be present in the grub boot list.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seemed to be solved already, I just want to add some information:

- You could not find the file `menu.lst` because it belongs to Grub Legacy. A lot of distros are switching to Grub 2 as the default boot loader, including Crunchbang.
- `grub.cfg` is there, but it isn't meant to be edited. The proper way to do it is to edit the files in `/etc/grub.d/` then run `grub-mkconfig`.
- Some distros (I think Debian based) have a script named `update-grub` that can probe your system, populate `/etc/grub.d/` and run `grub-mkconfig` in one shot.
- I agree with xenoterracide about the possibility of a bug in the installer. If you can reproduce it then consider submitting a bug report so the Crunchbang developers can fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. For what its worth, I think I'll first blog my experience before I forget it :). I will try to reproduce it when I get home.

Comment: Oh yeah!! I am able to reproduce it. No windows listing after installation, but is listed after running `sudo update-grub` from my shiny new crunchbang installation. I've got screenshots to prove it :). Who do I tell this?

Comment: @Shrikant There doesn't seem to be a bug tracker for CB, but I've seen people posting bugs on the [forum](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/forum/3/feedback-suggestions/).

Comment: oh boy, it needs registration. I'm spoilt by stackoverflow!

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurs with CD install, too. I got it fixed by running `sudo update-grub`